# Showing Type and Size of a Mat file loaded in Python

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, scipy, mat-file

I am new to python and I am converting Matlab code to Python. I have loaded the mat file which is a dictionary in Python. I can print the key names, but I cant understand how to show the types and size for the values

```
import scipy.io
import os 
import sys
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path = os.getcwd();
filename = "\mnist_uint8"
fullname = path+filename;
print("Reading file:"+fullname)
try:
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(fullname)
except IOError as err:
     print ("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
     sys.exit();
else:
    print("Successfully loaded mat file")

keys = mat.keys()

for key in keys:
    print(key)
```

I need to see "key " + " type" + "size" which can be seen below
[image]

Comment: the variables loaded from the MAT-file will be loaded as numpy arrays stored in a dictionary. So you can get the type and size of each array as usual: `arr.dtype` and `arr.shape`

Comment: Sometimes complicated Matlab structures are loaded as object dtype arrays, an array that contains other arrays.  You may need index with `[0]` or even `[()]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your last lines to:

```
for k in mat.keys():
    if not k.startswith('__'):
        print(k + " " + mat[k].dtype.name + " " + str(mat[k].shape))
```